# What exactly is a SIM card?

Tags: memory, embedded

Does a SIM card consist of only Flash memory or is there a microprocessor inside as well?

Comment: My answer was incorrect. It has been updated.

Comment: How does this related to reverse engineering?

Comment: @SDsolar first post or not isn't an explanantion for it on this site. It's off topic and this should be on http://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about regular hardware usage.

Comment: This question can be closed if that's the wish of the majority. I don't have any problem because I've already asked the question at the right forum (as was suggested).

Comment: @SDsolar: I'm not seeing your edits

Comment: I posted it as a new question here:  https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/15011/how-does-a-sim-card-work

Answer (score 2):

Correction:

> in fact many SIMs do contain a microprocessor for extra functionality [(see SIM Application Toolkit)](https://www.hacking-lab.com/cases/4053-sim-application-toolkit/index.html).

Thank you Igor Skochinsky for the correction.

According to [Karsten Nohl's presentation "Mobile Network Attack Evolution"](http://2014.phdays.com/program/tech/36814/), SIM cards contain an embedded [real-time operating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_operating_system), a filesystem and a Java VM :

[image: Presentation slide 1]

[image: Slide 2]

Here is a direct link to the presentation: https://www.slideshare.net/phdays/140521karsten-nohl-phdmobileattackevolution-35161629

See also: [4G Security: Hacking USB Modem and SIM Card via SMS](http://blog.ptsecurity.com/2014/12/4g-security-hacking-usb-modem-and-sim.html)

Comment: Excellent information.  I recently bought a $10 gadget called a "SIM card reader" but it shows nothing when I plug it into the USB port.  I suppose it must require some fancy software to  make all this work, eh?

Comment: I don't know but I'm sure that someone else here will. Maybe post a question about it?

Comment: Thanks for the info. However I'd like to know a few more things: 1. Since which generation did the SIM cards start to have a microprocessor? I mean, was it after 2G, 3G or 4G?   2. Mainly which microprocessor is used in the SIMs?

Comment: [http://simhacks.github.io/sim-cards/](http://simhacks.github.io/sim-cards/)

Comment: I couldn't find anywhere explicitly written that SIM cards contain microprocessor. Why do you think we don't have info about the microprocessors being used in our modern SIM cards like we have in the case of smartphones?

Comment: I can only offer speculation. My guess is that it is not immediately obvious that [SIMs are actually part of UICCs](http://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_ts/102200_102299/102221/08.02.00_60/ts_102221v080200p.pdf). Its much easier to recognize that smartphones are hand-held computers with CPUs, RAM, I/O, etc.

Comment: At last found a very good link: http://www.technoburst.net/2014/03/sim-cards-tutorial-part-2-architecture.html?m=1

Comment: My interest in the SIM card is how it affects the baseband portion of the phone.  Yes, I would like to back up my cards, but more than that, I would like to know how it is able to perform such low-level tasks.

Comment: @SDsolar interesting. I recommend posting a question about that