# How does a SIM card work?

Tags: firmware, memory

I understand that a SIM card has memory, and that some or maybe all of them also include microprocessors.

They act as peripherals that are more than just flash memory.

I would like to be able to read the contents and extract my contacts and messages, for backup, so I bought an el-cheapo "SIM Card Reader" that plugs into a USB port.  But when I plug it in it is as if it isn't even there.

So how can I get access to the data?

Secondly, I understand that they can affect the baseband portion of the cellphone, including frequency of operation and whatever codes are necessary to identify itself (IMEI) and to access a particular network (T-Mobile, AT&T, Verizen).  Again, it is clearly more than just flash memory.

So my question is, how exactly do they work, and how can I read the data from my phone's card?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

SIMs card are a type of Universal Integrated Circuit Card (UICC).

> how exactly do they work

According to [Karsten Nohl's presentation "Mobile Network Attack Evolution"](http://2014.phdays.com/program/tech/36814/), SIM cards contain an embedded [real-time operating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_operating_system), a filesystem and a Java VM:

[image: Presentation slide 1]

Here is the technical specification for UICCs, which describes exactly how they work:

[ETSI TS 102 221 V8.2.0 (2009-06)
Technical Specification for smart cards, the UICC-Terminal interface and physical and logical characteristics](http://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_ts/102200_102299/102221/08.02.00_60/ts_102221v080200p.pdf).

> how can I get access to the data?  how can I get into my own card?

This DefCon presentation ["DEF CON 21 - Karl Koscher and Eric Butler - The Secret Life of SIM Cards"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_-nxemBCcmU) video explains quite a bit about SIM cards and how to interface with them.

From the [presentation slides](http://simhacks.github.io/defcon-21/):

[image: Interfacing with SIM Cards 1]

They also had trouble:

[image: Interfacing with SIM Cards 2]

They found [SIM Alliance Loader](http://simalliance.org/key-technical-releases/) software...

[image: Interfacing with SIM Cards 3]

...but decided to use [GlobalPlatform](https://www.globalplatform.org/complianceproducts.asp) instead, which is far more complicated. In order to use GlobalPlatform to interface with the SIM card, the presenters drew on techniques presented in [Karsten Nohl's research](http://2014.phdays.com/program/tech/36814/).

Comment: Thank you, @SYS_V - I really appreciate you explaining this.  It isn't nearly as easy as reading a regular SD card at all.       (btw, cool handle -  I was trained on ATT System V also)

Comment: @SDsolar http://opensecuritytraining.info/SmartCards.html

Answer (score 1):

Found some good answers in this article:

[What Is A SIM Card (And What Comes Next)?](https://www.howtogeek.com/353634/what-is-a-sim-card/) (howtogeek.com)

EXCERPT:

> **What’s Stored On A SIM Card?**
>
> A SIM card stores the 15-digit International Mobile Subscriber Identity (IMSI) 
>   identifying the card on carrier’s mobile network. The IMSI is an
>   important part of the lookup process and determines the network to
>   which a mobile device connects.
>
> Along with the IMSI, a 128-bit value authentication key (Ki) is sent
>   to verify your SIM with the GSM cellular network. The Ki is assigned
>   by the operator and stored in a database on their network.
>
> A SIM card is also capable of storing SMS messages and the names and
>   phone numbers of up to 500 contacts, depending on the memory size of
>   the SIM card you have. If you have to change phones for whatever
>   reason, you’re able to transfer your contacts via the SIM card
>   painlessly.
>
> Most SIM cards contain between 64-128 KB of storage.
>
> **> How Does A SIM Work?**
>
> Essentially, a SIM card serves as your phone’s credentials to access
>   the carrier network. Because the SIM holds this information, you’re
>   able to pop it into any phone with the same carrier, or an unlocked
>   phone, to access the network.
>
> Here’s how it works:
>
> When you boot up your device, it obtains the IMSI from the SIM, and
>   then relays the IMSI to the network in order to request access.
>
> The operator network searches the database for your IMSI and the
>   associated Ki.
>
> Assuming your IMSI and Ki are verified, the operator
>   then generates a random number, signs it with your Ki using the GSM
>   cryptography algorithm for computing SRES_2, and creates a new unique
>   number.
>
> The network then sends that unique number back to the device,
>   which then passes it to the SIM to use in the same algorithm, creating
>   a third number.
>
> This number is then relayed back to the network.
>
> If both numbers match, the SIM card is deemed legitimate and is granted
>   access to the network.
>
> **So if you break the screen on your phone, while
>   it’s getting fixed you can take your SIM out and put it in a
>   replacement phone and still access phone calls, texts, and data from
>   your network.**