# How do the new Swedish implantable microchips work?

Tags: firmware, memory

So now we see that the Swedes are going large with their implantable chips which allow them to carry out certain kinds of transactions without using plastic.

[Thousands of people in Sweden get microchip implants for a new way of life](http://www.scmp.com/news/world/europe/article/2145896/thousands-people-sweden-get-microchip-implants-new-way-life)

Excerpt:

> It’s the size of a grain of rice but could hold the key to many
>   aspects of your life.
>
> A tiny microchip inserted under the skin can replace the need to carry
>   keys, credit cards and train tickets.
>
> That might sound like an Orwellian nightmare to some but in Sweden it
>   is a welcome reality for a growing number who favour convenience over
>   concerns of potential personal data violations.
>
> The small implants were first used in 2015 in Sweden – initially
>   confidentially – and several other countries.
>
> Swedes have gone on to be very active in microchipping, with scant
>   debate about issues surrounding its use, in a country keen on new
>   technology and where the sharing of personal information is held up as
>   a sign of a transparent society.
>
> Sweden’s SJ national railway company has won over some 130 users to
>   its microchip reservation service in a year.
>
> Conductors scan passengers’ hands after they book tickets online and
>   register them on their chip. Sweden has a track record on the sharing
>   of personal information, which may have helped ease the microchip’s
>   acceptance among the Nordic country’s 10 million-strong population.

**My question is:**

### How to read the information, then what information is stored in them?

**How do these microchips work?  Are they merely RFID units that store a single personal ID number?  Or is it something more complex, like a SIM card or Smartcard with some other kind of registration?**

Comment: If like a Smartcard or a SIM card, the "how it works" is covered very well here:  https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/15011/how-does-a-sim-card-work

Answer (score 2):

As I know they implant these NFC tag ICs:

[NTAG213_215_216: NFC Forum Type 2 Tag compliant IC with 144/504/888 bytes user memory](https://www.nxp.com/products/identification-and-security/smart-label-and-tag-ics/ntag/ntag-for-tags-labels/nfc-forum-type-2-tag-compliant-ic-with-144-504-888-bytes-user-memory:NTAG213_215_216) (nxp.com)

Excerpt:

> **FEATURES:**
>
> - Contactless transmission of data and supply energy
> - Operating frequency of 13.56 MHz
> - Data transfer of 106 kbit/s
> - Data integrity of 16-bit CRC, parity, bit coding, bit counting
> - Operating distance up to 100 mm (depending on various parameters as e.g. field strength and antenna geometry)
> - 7-byte serial number (cascade level 2 according to ISO/IEC 14443-3)
> - UID ASCII mirror for automatic serialization of NDEF messages
> - Automatic NFC counter triggered at read command
> - NFC counter ASCII mirror for automatic adding the NFC counter value to the NDEF message
> - ECC based originality signature
> - Fast read command
> - True anticollision
>
> **EEPROM**
>
> - 180, 540 or 924 bytes organized in 45, 135 or 231 pages with 4 bytes per page
> - 144, 504 or 888 bytes freely available user Read/Write area (36, 126 or 222 pages)
> - 4 bytes initialized capability container with one time programmable access bits
> - Field programmable read-only locking function per page for the first 16 pages
> - Field programmable read-only locking function above the first 16 pages per double page for NTAG213 or per 16 pages for NTAG215 and NTAG216
> - Configurable password protection with optional limit of unsuccessful attempts
> - Anti-tearing support for capability container (CC) and lock bits
> - ECC supported originality check
> - Data retention time of 10 years
> - Write endurance 100,000 cycles

Comment: Excellent answer.  For the first part of the question - is it simple or more complex.   Clearly it is not just simple.  And with this small amount of memory they clearly are not storing full biometrics.  I wonder what information is stored in the microchips...?

Comment: where did you find the exact model?

Comment: For example https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0AwnZ5wL2fI